# yq query with multiple env operator

Tags: yq

Given the following example.yaml definition:

```yaml
shop:
  europe:
    germany:
      shopA: shopBAddress
  asia:
    thailand:
      shopB:
        address: shopBAddress
```

I try to access `shop.europe.germany` path with use of `env` operator.

However when I do that I get error:

```sh
location=europe country=germany yq e '.shop.[env(location)].[env(country)]' example.yaml
Error: Bad expression, please check expression syntax
```

```sh
location=europe country=germany yq e '.shop.[env(location)][env(country)]' exmaple.yaml
Error: Cannot index array with 'germany' (strconv.ParseInt: parsing "germany": invalid syntax)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is right, but between two `env(..)` expressions or preceding one, you don't need the `.` operator, i.e. the below should work (verfied on version 4.11.2)

```sh
location=europe country=germany yq e '.shop[env(location)][env(country)]' yaml
```

Comment: After upgrafing of `yq` from version 4.7.1 to newest it started to work. Thank you